# Problem with history referencing operator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would really need someone's help, I am working on creating an harmonics pattern indicator, and I am getting this weired error message Invalid number of bars back [-1] within history-referencing operator. The value must be >=0 when the study is added to the chart. No matter what I do the starting index is less than 0, please help

```
//@version=7
study(title="Harmonic Patterns", overlay=true)

// Define inputs
lookback_bars = input(title="Lookback Bars", type=input.integer, defval=200)
min_ratio = input(title="Minimum Ratio", type=input.float, defval=0.618)
max_ratio = input(title="Maximum Ratio", type=input.float, defval=0.786)
show_bat = input(title="Show Bat Pattern", type=input.bool, defval=true)
show_gartley = input(title="Show Gartley Pattern", type=input.bool, defval=true)
show_butterfly = input(title="Show Butterfly Pattern", type=input.bool, defval=true)
show_crab = input(title="Show Crab Pattern", type=input.bool, defval=true)
show_cypher = input(title="Show Cypher Pattern", type=input.bool, defval=true)

// Define ratios
a_b = 0.382
a_c = 0.382
b_c = 0.618
c_d = 0.786
x_a = 0.382
d_x = 1.272

// Define variables
num_patterns = 0

// Define colors
bat_color = color.red
gartley_color = color.orange
butterfly_color = color.yellow
crab_color = color.green
cypher_color = color.blue

// Define arrays
ratios = array.new_float()
patterns = array.new_string()
indexes = array.new_int()
prices = array.new_float()

// Additional function to check for patterns
// Modified fib function
fib(n) =>
    var float a = 1
    var float b = 1
    if n < 2
        a
    else
        for i = 2 to n
            a := a + b
            a, b := b, a
        a

// Additional function to check for patterns
pattern_found(_pattern, _ab, _ad, _cd, _xd, _bc) =>
    if _pattern == "BAT"
        _ad > min_ratio and _ad < max_ratio and _xd > 0.886 and _xd < 1.13
    else
        if _pattern == "GARTLEY"
            _ab > min_ratio and _ab < max_ratio and _cd > 1.27 and _cd < 1.618
        else
            if _pattern == "BUTTERFLY"
                _ab > min_ratio and _ab < max_ratio and _cd > 1.618 and _cd < 2.24
            else
                if _pattern == "CRAB"
                    _ad > min_ratio and _ad < max_ratio and _xd > 1.618 and _xd < 2.618
                else
                    if _pattern == "CYPHER"
                        _ab > min_ratio and _ab < max_ratio and _cd > 0.786 and _cd < 0.886 and _bc < 0.382
                    else
                        false

// Calculate ratios and patterns
for i = max(bar_index - lookback_bars, 0) to bar_index - 2
    high_price = high[i]
    low_price = low[i]
    a_price = high[i+1]
    b_price = fib(1) * (a_price - low_price) + low_price
    c_price = fib(2) * (a_price - low_price) + low_price
    d_price = fib(3) * (a_price - low_price) + low_price
    x_price = a_price - x_a * (a_price - d_price)
    
    ab = abs(a_price - b_price) / abs(a_price - c_price)
    bc = abs(b_price - c_price) / abs(a_price - c_price)
    cd = abs(c_price - d_price) / abs(a_price - c_price)
    ad = abs(a_price - d_price) / abs(a_price - c_price)
    xd = abs(x_price - d_price) / abs(a_price - d_price)
    
    if pattern_found("BAT", ab, ad, cd, xd, bc)
        array.push(ratios, ad)
        array.push(patterns, "BAT")
    else
        if pattern_found("GARTLEY", ab, ad, cd, xd, bc)
            array.push(ratios, ab)
            array.push(patterns, "GARTLEY")
        else
            if pattern_found("BUTTERFLY", ab, ad, cd, xd, bc)
                array.push(ratios, ab)
                array.push(patterns, "BUTTERFLY")
            else
                if pattern_found("CRAB", ab, ad, cd, xd, bc)
                    array.push(ratios, ad)
                    array.push(patterns, "CRAB")
                else
                    if pattern_found("CYPHER", ab, ad, cd, xd, bc)
                        array.push(ratios, ab)
                        array.push(patterns, "CYPHER")

    array.push(indexes, i)
    array.push(prices, high[i])


// Plot patterns
for i = 0 to array.size(ratios) - 1
    var color line_color = na
    pattern = array.get(patterns, i)
    if pattern == "BAT"
        line_color := bat_color
    else if pattern == "GARTLEY"
        line_color := gartley_color
    else if pattern == "BUTTERFLY"
        line_color := butterfly_color
    else if pattern == "CRAB"
        line_color := crab_color
    else if pattern == "CYPHER"
        line_color := cypher_color
    line.new(x1=bar_index - array.get(indexes, i), y1=array.get(prices, i), x2=bar_index - array.get(indexes, i), y2=array.get(prices, i) + tr, color=line_color, width=2)

// Label patterns
for i = 0 to array.size(ratios) - 1
    pattern = array.get(patterns, i)
    ratio = array.get(ratios, i)
    label_text = pattern + "\n" + tostring(ratio, "#.##")
    var color label_color = na
    if pattern == "BAT"
        label_color := bat_color
    else if pattern == "GARTLEY"
        label_color := gartley_color
    else if pattern == "BUTTERFLY"
        label_color := butterfly_color
    else if pattern == "CRAB"
        label_color := crab_color
    else if pattern == "CYPHER"
        label_color := cypher_color
    label.new(x=bar_index - array.get(indexes, i), y=array.get(prices, i), text=label_text, color=label_color, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_down)
```

Comment: Your code shouldn't work at all as version=7 doesn't exist. Where do your code comes from ?

Comment: I commented version=7 manually for my own reference,  it is actually version 4

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you are trying to access a serie with a `[-1]`.

What I would do to find the problematic line of code is:

- **Gradually removing stuff until it runs**: So comments out parts of the code that plays arround series with the `[]` operator, until the code runs without the error.  You might have to patch it up a bit for this to work.  When it runs, you can now guess that the code you just commented is the cause.  You could try to debug by ploting the index that you try to send to the serie: `plot(mySerieIndex)`
- Or another way is to copy the script on the side, and start from scratch, **gradually introducing the code until you get the error**.  Same as above, you found the spot where the problem is.  Try to see what index  you try to pass and fix the code.

Good luck with your indicator!

PS: I was not allowed to comment, so here is an "answer"